# How is a signed kernel image created?

Tags: kernel

There are two source packages in Debian: linux and linux-signed. The signed images show the latter as their source. But it is much smaller than the former. What's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm sorry but this is not about Ubuntu and therefore off topic since programming questions are far of the scope we cant provide support for that, so you might be better off asking your question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please do not cross-post, flag your answer instead for moderator attention if you wish it to be migrated there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- `linux-signed` source  depends on `linux` binaries, may be it just repackage them:

  [linux-signed_4.4.0-22.40.dsc](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-signed/linux-signed_4.4.0-22.40.dsc) or its `debian/control`

  ```
  Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), lsb-release, python3, python3-apt, 
  sbsigntool, linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic (>= 4.4.0-22.40), 
  linux-image-4.4.0-22-lowlatency (>= 4.4.0-22.40)
  ```

  (I broke the line just for readable format)
- How it is created?

  Check its `debian/rules`, it just download them already signed from somewhere.

  Could this be helpful: [SecureBoot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot)